# CakePHP saveAll not saving key of 2nd level dependent

Tags: cakephp

I am using cake PHP 2.x. My Database is set up like this.

Rating Has One Review

Review Has Many Photo

```
data => array(
    'Rating' => array(
        'rating' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'listing_id' => '55'
        ),
    'Review' => array(
        'title' => 'Good Service',
        'date_visited' => array(
            'month' => '05',
            'day' => '28',
            'year' => '2013',
            ),
        'service_used' => 'Easy Checkout',
        'description' => 'After a fairly quick check-in, the check out service was also breeze ',
        'Photo' => array(
            (int) 1 => array(
                'title' => 'Test',
                'photo' => array(
                'name' => '2.JPG',
                ),
            'listing_id' => '55',
            'user_id' => '1'
            )
           )
        )
    )
```

Review.php

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Photo' => array(
        'className'  => 'Photo',
        'conditions' =>'',
        'order'      => ''
        )
);
```

Photo.php

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Review' => array(
        'className' => 'Review',
        'foreignKey' => 'review_uuid',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Listing' => array(
        'className' => 'Listing',
        'foreignKey' => 'listing_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

And Finally RatingsController.php

```
$this->Rating->create();

if ($this->Rating->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The rating has been saved'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

The issue is all the data is getting saved, except review_uuid (which is also being created simultaneously) )in Photos model.

```
mysql> select id,user_id,listing_id,review_uuid,title,photo,photo_dir from photos where ID=26;
    +----+---------+------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------    +
    | id | user_id | listing_id | review_uuid | title | photo                                | photo_dir |
    +----+---------+------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------    +
    | 26 |       1 |         55 | NULL        | Test  | 1a107372ef53ba26d7748a50c25e6b27.jpg | 01/77/74  |
    +----+---------+------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like your defining the foreign key in the `hasMany` relationship in `Review` found in `Photo`, your not completing the relation.

Your `hasMany` array in `Review.php` should look like:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Photo' => array(
        'className'  => 'Photo',
        'foreignKey' => 'review_uuid',
        'conditions' =>'',
        'order'      => ''
        )
);
```

Note the `foreignKey` parameter.  You are telling Cake that `Review` has many photos and each photo record has a foreign key named `review_uuid` used to identify it's relationship to a review.  You were defining the foreign key in your `belongsTo` array in the `Photo` model but not in your `hasMany` array in the `Review` model, so the relation was never completed.

You should also define a `belongsTo` relation between `Review` and `Rating`

In `Review.php`:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Photo' => array(
        'className'  => 'Photo',
        'foreignKey' => 'review_uuid',
        'conditions' =>'',
        'order'      => ''
        )
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Rating' => array(
        'className' => 'Rating',
        'foreignKey' => 'rating_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. foreignKey was missing. wrt belongsTo, it was already set up in my model. I had given only partial tags in question to avoid a long long question.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out.